# onMove for @ObservedResults

Tags: swiftui, realm

I am displaying a list of items coming from `ObservedResults`. (Without using an `ItemGroup` that has a `List<Item>`)

```
class Item: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId    
    @Persisted var name: String
    // @Persisted var order: Int
}
```

```
struct ItemsView: View {
    
    @ObservedResults(Item.self) var items
        
    var body: some View {
        if items.isEmpty {
            Text("No items")
        } else {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    ItemView(item: item)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: $items.remove)
                //.onMove
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a standard/recommend way to do implement `onMove`?

Comment: I believe that since Realm Results collections are unordered there would be no direct `move` function because ordering could change. Whereas a `List` has a guaranteed order and a `move` function would make sense. See [Results indexes may change](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/supported-types/#collections-are-live) and I think @ObservedResults follow that design pattern, even if they are mutable. The solution is to create an ItemGroup, which contains a `RealmSwift.List<Item>()` of Items - then ObserveResults on the ItemGroup. onDelete, onMove etc then work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rh05puZsh6o) video.

First, make sure that new items have the highest `order`.

```
// Add item to collection
let order = (items.max(of: \Item.order) ?? 0) + 1
let item = Item(name: name, order: order)
$items.append(item)
```

(It’s probably a good idea to create an index `@Persisted(indexed: true) var order: Int`)

When moving an item, displace other items  by incrementing or decrementing their `order` by 1.

[image: displace up]

[image: displace down]

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct ItemsView: View {
    
    @ObservedResults(Item.self, sortDescriptor: SortDescriptor(keyPath: "order", ascending: true)) var items
    
    @Environment(\.realm) var realm
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                ItemView(item: item)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: $items.remove)
            .onMove  { indexSet, destination in
                for index in indexSet { // not sure how we can move more than one item at a time
                    let itemToMove = items[index]
                    let orderAtDestination = orderAtDestination(destination)
                    
                    // move item down
                    if itemToMove.order < orderAtDestination {
                        let start = itemToMove.order + 1
                        let end = orderAtDestination - 1
                        let itemsToDisplace = items.where { item in
                            item.order.contains(start...end)
                        }
                        // displace upwards
                        itemsToDisplace.forEach { item in
                            if let item = item.thaw(){ // is there a way to use $items[index].order += 1
                                try! realm.write { // safe to not catch exceptions?
                                    item.order -= 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // save
                        if let itemToMove = itemToMove.thaw() {
                            try! realm.write {
                                 itemToMove.order = end
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // move item up
                    else if itemToMove.order > orderAtDestination {
                        let start = orderAtDestination
                        let end = itemToMove.order - 1
                        let itemsToDisplace = items.where { item in
                            item.order.contains(start...end)
                        }
                        // displace downwards
                        itemsToDisplace.forEach { item in
                            if let item = item.thaw(){
                                try! realm.write {
                                    item.order += 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // save
                        if let itemToMove = itemToMove.thaw() {
                            try! realm.write {
                                 itemToMove.order = start
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func orderAtDestination(_ destination: Int) -> Int{
        if destination < items.count {
            return items[destination].order
        }
        // if an array has 4 elements, there are 5 possible destinations
        // a destination of 4 means to move the item after the last item (with index 3)
        return (items.max(of: \Item.order) ?? 0) + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `ObservedResults` come with `.onMove(perform: $items.move)`

Comment: @loremipsum I could be 100% incorrect but I believe that since `Results` objects are unordered, so there is no static index for each object. The `sorted` clause then becomes void as what if you move objects that conflict with the defined sort order? Whereas `List` objects are ordered and it makes sense have a `.move` function.  I don't believe this answer will work (consistently) as it's moving objects around in an unordered list where the order could change at any time.

Comment: @loremipsum No it doesn't. Usually people create an item group with a `List<Item>` and call `onMove` on that list.

Comment: @Jay The items are ordered with a custom field `@ObservedResults(Item.self, sortDescriptor: SortDescriptor(keyPath: "order", ascending: true)) var items`. The solution seems to work well when I'm testing [full code](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/realm-swift-template/blob/9bd4a21b28b44e751ecdc3a5f545386b7178e3d9/simple-onMove/RealmTemplate/Views/ItemsView.swift).

Comment: @BPDev The sorted results orders the data in the Results, there is no defined ordering of a results object. Therefor the positioning of the objects could change as additional objects were added or removed as the Realm will re-order them. So - in a nutshell, this solution may work but I feel it could be intermittent as index is NOT a static value - a better bet is to use a List.